# Login hanging when testing cypress with no logs

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, cypress

```
it('Can login with modal', () => {
      cy.get('.menu-item')
        .contains('Sign In')
        .click()

      cy.get('.model-wrapper').should('have.css', 'opacity', '1')
      cy.get('.form-heading').should('have.text', 'Welcome Back')

      cy.get('[name=email]').type(email)
      cy.get('[name=password]').type(password)
      cy.get('[type=submit]').click()
    })
  })
```

Here is the code and it does not go through with the login upon button click. Just goes into the loading state.

Here is the full file: https://github.com/Lambda-School-Labs/forest-fire-watch-fe/blob/np-cypress/fireflight/cypress/integration/login_test.spec.js

I also have chromeWebSecurity in my cypress.json file set to false.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely due to **indexedDb.delete** which blocks firebase from init/running. In addition, it's not the right approach to log out. You should use **firebase.auth().logout**

I'd suggest you expose login/logout through Cypress commands in **commands.js**. The cypress + firebase integration is as simple as below

```
  const fbConfig = {
    apiKey: 'your api key',
    authDomain: '<your auth>.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: 'https://<your db>.firebaseio.com',
    projectId: 'your project id',
    storageBucket: 'your bucket.appspot.com'
  }

  firebase.initializeApp(fbConfig)

  Cypress.Commands.add('login', (email, password) => {
    return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  })

  Cypress.Commands.add('logout', () => {
    return firebase.auth().signOut()
  })
```

In tests, you can replace **indexedDB.delete** with **cy.logout()**